# Best way to add image to mp3 file with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, image, mp3, exec

I am looking for a way to embed album art in a mp3 file with PHP, either through a some kind of PHP script or through exec() and a Linux command.

Answer (score 0):

PHP [**supports**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.id3-set-tag.php) setting ID3 tags, but it looks like it does not support images.

If you want to add image you can make use of the [**eyeD3**](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) Linux command with `--add-image` option.